# onPostExecute() is waiting too long?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have some control and for this reason i did some threads.I want to show loading bar one screen to another screen with asycntask.My problem is Loading bar is showing and disapper  quickly and then waiting for the same screen alot without loading bar.And  after for a while it is going second screen. I think post execute is not working for me correctly.Can anybody help me?

This is my code:

```
private class ProgressBarAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        /** This callback method is invoked, before starting the background process */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            /** Creating a progress dialog window */
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

            /** Close the dialog window on pressing back button */
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

            /** Setting a horizontal style progress bar */
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

            /** Setting a message for this progress dialog
             * Use the method setTitle(), for setting a title
             * for the dialog window
             *  */
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, 
                    "Giriş yapıyorsunuz", "Lütfen bekleyin...");



        }

        /** This callback method is invoked on calling execute() method
         * on an instance of this class */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {

            try {
                startMyApplication() ;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /** This callback method is invoked when publishProgress()
         * method is called */
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
        }

        /** This callback method is invoked when the background function
         * doInBackground() is executed completely */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (mid > 0) {
                Intent btn_login = new Intent(
                        getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
                startActivity(btn_login);
            }
            else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("GİRİŞ");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Kullanıcı adı veya Parola Hatalı Lütfen tekrar deneyin.");

                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("TAMAM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();         
            }

            //run();                    
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

This is startmyapp theads:

```
public void startMyApplication() throws InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    FutureTask<String> futureOne = new FutureTask<String>(
            new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    if (isOnline()) {
                        // Call Login Web Service with username and password and get mid
                        mid = callLoginWS(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());                            
                        if (mid > 0) {
                            //callPasswordGeneratorWS(mid);
                            // Insert mid and username into sqllite
                            dbInstance.insertMerch(mid,username.getText().toString());
                        }
                        Log.i("futureone", "futureone");

                    }
                    return "TEST";  
                }
            });

    FutureTask<String> futureTwo = new FutureTask<String>(
            new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    // Get mid from database
                    mid = dbInstance.selectMerch(username.getText().toString());
                    return "TEST";
                }

            });



    // ... Dispatch
    // Check if user exists previously
    // ... Dispatch     
    mid = dbInstance.selectMerch(username.getText().toString());
    dbInstance.close();


    executor.execute(futureOne);
    while (!(futureOne.isDone())) {
        executor.execute(futureTwo);
    }
    Log.i("login","new login");
    //}
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: What is inside this function ` startMyApplication() ;`

Answer (score 3):

This section is causing delay.

```
while (!(futureOne.isDone())) {
        executor.execute(futureTwo);
    }
```

As here you are blocking your current thread to complete. and waiting for the  `futureOne` to complete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to execute the *startMyApplication* method without *ExecutorService*. When you run your code in *doInBackground* you are already in a different thread (correct me if I am wrong), so run your code without using extra threads. Do this and check if everything is working. 


Also, I have noticed that you don't call the *publishProgress(Progress... values)* method anywhere at *doInBackground* method. So, you cannot publish the right value for the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong. You are already executing startMyApplication() asynchronously using AsyncTask so why to create FutureTask. You are already in background task. (Considering mid is long)
Try to modify ur code like this,

```
    public Long startMyApplication(){
       if (isOnline()) {
          // Call Login Web Service with username and password and get mid
          mid = callLoginWS(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());                            
          if (mid > 0) {
                //callPasswordGeneratorWS(mid);
                // Insert mid and username into sqllite
                dbInstance.insertMerch(mid,username.getText().toString());
          }
          Log.i("futureone", "futureone");

          }
      mid = dbInstance.selectMerch(username.getText().toString()); //OR directly returning mid without fetching from db as it will be same.
      return mid;
    }
```

Now in doInBackground.

```
@Override
protected Long doInBackground(Void...params) {
            Long temp = -1l;
            try {
                temp = startMyApplication() ;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return temp;
 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long mid) {
mProgressDialog.dismiss(); //First dismiss the progress bar.
//Rest of ur code will go same in this. Remember mid is now accessible correctly.
}
```

Change the following line,

```
private class ProgressBarAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
```

by

```
private class ProgressBarAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long>
```

This might work for you as far as I understood it.